# Excel consolidate sum yields different column total

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I have two columns that look like this:

```
Make/Model      Parc
Abarth*500      15
Abarth*500      19
Abarth*500      2
Abarth*500      14
Abarth*500      15
Abarth*500      25
Abarth*500      20
Abarth*500      17
Abarth*500C     12
Abarth*500C     16
Abarth*500C     23
Abarth*500C     18
Abarth*500C     1
Alfa Romeo*145  405
Alfa Romeo*145  431
Alfa Romeo*146  36
Alfa Romeo*146  80
Alfa Romeo*146  121
Alfa Romeo*146  72
Alfa Romeo*146  39
```

etc...

The sum of the values in the "Parc" column is 10,475,387.

I perform a consolidate on this table to remove the repetitions in "Make/Model" and sum the values in the "Parc" column for each "Make/Model."

[image: Excel Consolidate]

Once I perform the consolidation, everything looks as expected:

```
Make/Model      Parc
Abarth*500      127
Abarth*500C     70
Alfa Romeo*145  836
Alfa Romeo*146  348
Alfa Romeo*147  3848
Alfa Romeo*155  29
Alfa Romeo*156  3148
Alfa Romeo*159  573
Alfa Romeo*164  111
```

etc...

So what's the problem? The new sum of the "Parc" column is 10,554,076! When I perform random "spot" checks everything seems correct. I do not understand how the sum could have gone up? I have over 18,000 rows in this dataset so individually checking all of the data would be very time consuming.

You can find the full dataset here:
[Excel File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BycHsjONLzDNLXpXdFVDYTA1WTQ/view?usp=sharing)

Edit:
I added the screenshot of me using the consolidate tool to give you an idea of what I did to get this result.

Edit 2:
I have tried removing all formatting. Also, these numbers are all integers and the option to "Automatically insert a decimal point" is not checked. I have also tried creating a new column of =INT() values to ensure they are all integers. My results are exactly the same in all cases.

Comment: What's your formula? Also make sure that there aren't any spaces before/after the names in your original data (perhaps just run `TRIM()` on all of them)?

Comment: How can we troubleshoot your formula if don't have a clue about it? Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it** in the question itself.

Comment: @A.S.H No formulas are used. Edited to add consolidate window image.

Comment: @BruceWayne Thanks for making a suggestion, but TRIM() did not change anything. I did not expect it to work because even if the consolidate did not categorize the labels correctly, it still should sum the values of combined rows and return the same total.

Comment: @A.S.H I believe this question can be re-opened as I have now provided all of the data and clarified my method. Thank you.

Comment: No problem for me, but it wont reopen if I vote alone for it , which I already did :). Maybe it is better (and surely faster) to write a new question, (may be with a mention about this to make it safer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The asteriks is a special character in Excel. Easiest solution that I know is to replace the asterisk by a space. To do so in the find/replace box, type '~*' in the find box and ' ' in the replace then do replace all (without quotes).

Both sum and sumif then yield 10,475,387.

Comment: This is the answer. The asterisk was there because I need to spit text to columns at the asterisk as the next step. I will replace with another character. Thanks!