# Excel consolidate yields incorrect list of unique values

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I have two columns that look like this:

```
Make/Model      Parc
Abarth*500      15
Abarth*500      19
Abarth*500      2
Abarth*500      14
Abarth*500      15
Abarth*500      25
Abarth*500      20
Abarth*500      17
Abarth*500C     12
Abarth*500C     16
Abarth*500C     23
Abarth*500C     18
Abarth*500C     1
Alfa Romeo*145  405
Alfa Romeo*145  431
Alfa Romeo*146  36
Alfa Romeo*146  80
Alfa Romeo*146  121
Alfa Romeo*146  72
Alfa Romeo*146  39
```

etc...

The sum of the values in the "Parc" column is 10,475,387.

I perform a consolidate on this table to remove the repetitions in "Make/Model" and sum the values in the "Parc" column for each "Make/Model."

[image]

Once I perform the consolidation, everything looks as expected:

```
Make/Model      Parc
Abarth*500      127
Abarth*500C     70
Alfa Romeo*145  836
Alfa Romeo*146  348
Alfa Romeo*147  3848
Alfa Romeo*155  29
Alfa Romeo*156  3148
Alfa Romeo*159  573
Alfa Romeo*164  111
```

etc...

So what's the problem? The new sum of the "Parc" column is 10,554,076! Verification against an alternate method indicates that the column of unique labels is incorrect in seemingly random places. I also do not understand how the total sum could have gone up. I have over 18,000 rows in this dataset so individually checking all of the data would be very time consuming.

You can find the full dataset here:
[Excel File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BycHsjONLzDNLXpXdFVDYTA1WTQ/view?usp=sharing)

What have I tried?

I have tried removing all formatting. Also, these numbers are all integers and the option to "Automatically insert a decimal point" is not checked. I have also tried creating a new column of =INT() values to ensure they are all integers. My results are exactly the same in all cases.

I posted this question yesterday and it was put on hold because it could not be reproduced without the full dataset: [Excel consolidate sum yields different column total](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44959579/excel-consolidate-sum-yields-different-column-total)

EDIT:
As [Mauricio Noris Freire](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8216801/mauricio-noris-freire) has shown, you can create a unique item column using advanced filter, and then use SUMIF to solve this problem correctly. I still would like to know why the Excel data tool consolidate does not work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your observations are correct.  Both `Consolidate` and `SUMIFS` are being affected by the asterisks in your data.  If you remove the asterisks, or, as I did, replace them with a pipe `|` character, your totals will match.

You could also get a correct report by using a Pivot Table

Examine, for example the output for the Mercedes*190

In the raw data, we show these lines if we filter for that value:

[image]

In the Consolidation report, we see that the total for Mercedes*190 will include both that car, and also the Mercedes*A190.  In other words the A190 is being counted twice, because of the wild card issue.

[image]

I suspect this is some kind of design flaw.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that value is wrong. Take a look into the file which I have recriate the parc column using a sumif formula
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4_RkQvn7-_TeG9kSE5NV0Z6Umc

Comment: Your SUMIF does seem to work correctly. I still don't understand why the consolidate tool does not work. Take a look at my consolidate next to your SUMIF: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BycHsjONLzDNM051VWtBeUJhaVE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Your "distinct" list is different of mine. I took the remove duplicates only to select one row by kind and then I have made the sumif..... I don't know why your list is different. Look at the row 55  Audi*Allroad Quattro vs Audi*Cabriolet

Comment: I agree...I also don't know why the consolidate made my list different from yours.

Comment: @MauricioNorisFreire You did **NOT** use `SUMIF`; you used `SUM(IF(...`  The former would have shown the same error since wild cards are accepted; the latter does not show the errors since wild cards are not accepted.